# How to use Ingress Nginx Controller to route traffic to private pods Internally

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks, nginx-ingress, external-dns

**Problem**: I am currently using ingress-nginx in my EKS cluster to route traffic to services that need public access.

**My use case**: I have services I want to deploy in the same cluster but don't want them to have public access. I only want the pods to communicate will all other services within the cluster. Those pods are meant to be private because they're backend services and only need pod-to-pod communication. How do I modify my ingress resource for this purpose?

**Cluster Architecture**: All services are in the private subnets of the cluster while the load-balancer is in the public subnets

**Additional note:** I am using `external-dns` to dynamically create the subdomains for the hosted zones. The hosted zone is public

Thanks

Below are my `service.yml` and `ingress.yml` for public services. I want to modify these files for private services

**service.yml**

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: myapp
  namespace: myapp 
  annotations:
    external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/hostname: myapp.dev.com
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 3000
  selector:
    app: myapp
```

**ingress.yml**

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: myapp
  namespace: myapp 
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
  labels:
    app: myapp
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
  - myapp.dev.com
  secretName: myapp-staging
  rules:
  - host: myapp.dev.com
    http:
      paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: Prefix
          backend:
            service:
              name: 'myapp'
              port:
                number: 80
```

Comment: what kubernetes version you are using?

Comment: @Bazhikov Kubenetes 1.21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this what you have the Ingress already should work and your services are meant to be private(if you set like this in your public cloud cluster), except the Ingress itself. You can update the ConfigMap to use the PROXY protocol so that you can pass proxy information to the Ingress Controller:

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nginx-config
  namespace: nginx-ingress
data:
  proxy-protocol: "True"
  real-ip-header: "proxy_protocol"
  set-real-ip-from: "0.0.0.0/0"
```

And then: `kubectl apply -f common/nginx-config.yaml`

Now you can deploy any app that you want to have private with the name specified (for example your `myapp` Service in your yaml file provided.

If you are a new to Kubernetes Networking, then [this article](https://getenroute.io/blog/ingress-controller-kubernetes-api-gateway-secure-service-jwt-oauth-oidc-network-namespace/) would be useful for you or in official Kubernetes documentation

[Here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/_print/#other-elb-annotations) you can find other ELB annotations that may be useful for you

Comment: Great help and great resources